Can I pass strings as bytes into a Solang contract and mint tokens from a Node.js client on Solana?
I am working on a project using Solang to write smart contracts for the Solana blockchain, and I have a few questions regarding the interaction between a Solang contract and a Node.js client.
What I'm Trying to Achieve:
I want to mint tokens and expose functions in my Solang contract that can be called from a Node.js client.
One of the inputs I need to pass into the contract is a string (specifically a URL) that a user submits.
I am using the bytes type in the function signature of my Solang contract to handle this dynamic data (since Solana doesn't natively support strings like Ethereum).
My Setup:
The Solang contract has a function to mint tokens and accept a bytes input as a string.
The Node.js client will interact with the contract, passing a URL (as a string, which will be converted to bytes) into the contract function.
Here is an example of the function signature in the Solang contract:
function submitURL(bytes memory url) public {
    // logic to mint tokens
}

In my Node.js client, I plan to call this function with a string that is converted to bytes:
const url = "https://example.com";
const urlBytes = Buffer.from(url);  // Convert string to bytes

// Call contract's submitURL method passing the `urlBytes`

My Question:
Is it possible to pass bytes (converted from a string) into a Solang contract like this?
Are there any potential issues or pitfalls with using bytes for this purpose?
Is this approach feasible for interacting with Solang contracts from a Node.js client?
I want to avoid using anchor, and just deploy my .sol->.so file using the solana command line, and write a node program to interact with it.
Is this possible to achieve in one file?  My idea is yes, but after some reading I'm no longer certain.
Any guidance or feedback would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Yes, you can pass bytes from Node.js into Solang just like that.
This method is absolutely feasible for working with Solang on Solana. You don’t need Anchor if you’re comfortable with raw Solana commands. You can deploy your .so file via the Solana CLI, then write a single Node.js file that bundles everything, (Load the program, build the instruction, pass in the bytes, and call the contract function) all in one place. It’s a bit like baking a pie from scratch, but it’s all under your control, and it works.
Think of bytes as a simple box where you store your string data before sending it off. Converting a string to bytes in Node.js (using Buffer.from) is a valid way to do this.
Pitfalls? Watch out for data size limits. Bytes can blow up if your URL is huge. Also ensure you handle any encoding issues, so the contract interprets your bytes correctly. But for typical URL lengths, it should be fine.

Thank you so much for confirming, it's a good sanity check.  Alright, i'm still getting errors like "Error processing Instruction 0: invalid program argument" so I have no idea how to debug it unfortunately, but at least you have confirmed what I suspected to be possible is possible.  It's a single file, optimistically that is quite alright.
